# How can I make footer in this case and how to center image?

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend, footer

How can I make footer in this case? When I try to do this, the footer text overlaps the top of the page. I want this footer on bootom of the page.

Second question. How can I center for height and width this header because now is only width centered.

And my last question is this page layout correct? Is it not about appearance.

```css
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }

body {
    font-family: Garamond;
}
header {
    background-color: #3CB371;
    width: auto;
    height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
section {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 450px;
}

.right {
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 45%;
    height: 450px;
}
img {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: dotted;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #3CB371;
}
footer {
    background-color: red;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Some H2<h2>
    </header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="right">
                <h3>Some H3</h3>
                <ol>
                    <li value="5">Some5 LI</li>
                    <li value="9">Some9 LI</li>
                    <li value="20">Some20 LI</li>
                    <ol>
                        <a href="url1" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                            <li>Some href1 text</li>
                            <a href="url" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                                <li>Some href2 text</li>
                    </ol>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <img src="imgurl" alt="Image" class="center">
            </div>
        </article>
</section>
<footer>
Some footer text
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to close tags like `<a>` and `<h2>`. You made some mistakes about closing tags.

Second, you must give `bottom:0;` to your footer, if you dont, your footer will be placed somewhere weird because of `position:absolute;`.

And lastly, you can use `float:right;` instead of giving `position:absolute;` `right:0;` in your `.right` div.

Comment: When I change position:absolute and right:0 to float:right then all my page go up and cut some text etc.
bottom:0 works in footer but how to prevent it from overlapping the section tag?

Comment: @grtyz you have used position:absolute; to center your section, am I right? So this is not the best way to center. I edited your code a little bit but I forgot to tell you that you have to change your centering style. Just delete CSS content of your section and add `display:table; margin:0 auto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <style>
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}    
body {
    min-height:600px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Garamond;
    background-color: #3CB371;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    line-height:150px
}

section {
    min-height:450px;
}

.left {
    
    width: 55%;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
}

.right {
    border-right:1px solid;
    width: 45%;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
}
img {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 15px;
    border: dotted;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #3CB371;
}
footer {
    footer:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black
}
ol{
    text-align:center
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Some H2</h2>
    </header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="right">
                <h3>Some H3</h3>
                <ol>
                    <li value="5">Some5 LI</li>
                    <li value="9">Some9 LI</li>
                    <li value="20">Some20 LI</li>
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="url" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Some href1 text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="url" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
                            Some href2 text</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <img src="imgurl" alt="Image" class="center">
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </article>
</section>
<footer>
Some footer text
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

i have made some changes in your code and have also added border so it would help you understand easily

Comment: add this css in your style.css file and check it.